# 2D Dynamic HW Position on Image WPF View

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, 2d

I am working on a .Net WPF app that displays fixed network gateways (switches, routers) inside an office premises.
I am looking at represent the office plant on 2D view, and dynamically/automatically place items on it that represent those network devices to give an overview of their position.

I have thought about storing the coordinates XY (pixel) with the HW Details, so the end-user can just adjust those coordinates to move the device to a new position on the image. 
1. Will this work? 
2. Is this a very rudimentary solution? Will it adapt if the Window size changes.
3. Can anyone recommend a Nuget Package ? 
4. Can anyone recommend me an algorithm?

Appreciate your help.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice DragCanvas Demo at [codeplex](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas). Which shows a lot of what you want to do.

You can resize the window and handle the event to resize all the controls on the canvas but it sounds like if this solution just used inside your company, I would avoid the extra code just allow a reasonable fixed window size so you can store the offsets of each network image and restore them when the program is reloaded (but yes you can do it).

1. Yes this will work
2. You do not need a complex solution?
3. No packages needed.
4. algorithms not really needed. ( google "resizing canvas controls")

Figure out how you want to save/load the positions in file or Db and you are done.

Comment: I was probably not google the right thing from start, will start there. What you describe is exactly what I was thinking. However, I do wanna make as dynamic as possible as the background image will change overtime, and will prob not be maintaining it, I our multiple offices to have their own and manage as they grow in devices and space easily.

Comment: If each office is not linked together then replacing your background.png file should be easy enough by a non-technical person. If you want to allow changing the image in the application then simply add a file-uploader that replaces the background image is another option, or if you want to store and update everything then I would simply use a json config file that stores the office id and asset positions, many options.